# Intersect shapefile with raster, then determine proportion of each raster value?

Tags: arcpy, raster, shapefile, statistics, zonal-statistics

Using the arcpy module in Python, I want to find the proportion of each pixel value within the boundary of an overlaying polygon.  (The polygon is in a shapefile.)

For example, there are 10 possible values in the raster, and intersecting the polygon 17% of the pixels are `class1`, 8% are `class2`, etc.

This may involve use of the *Zonal Statistics* tool, but apparently I'm having trouble working out the syntax programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Tabulate Area (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w2000000) rather than Zonal Statistics if you are after proportions.

[image]

---

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "C:/sapyexamples/data"
TabulateArea("zonedata.shp", "IDStr", "valueraster", "VALUE",
             "C:/sapyexamples/output/areatable.dbf", 2)
```

Comment: This is certainly one way to go, but I think I have what i want using ZonalHistogram: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000w6000000